# Skeletal animation with three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to animate a 3d object using three.js .I do have the bone structure that i load in the geometry of the object; each bone has parent, pos, rotq, scl. Also the geometry gets the skinIndices and skinWeights responsible for the skinning. The animation it is created to respect the structure:

```
animation: {

    name: "nameOfAnimation",
    length: 1201,
    fps: 0.03,  // fpms actually
    hierarchy: [

    { parent: -1,
    keys: [

    { time: 0,
    pos: [ x, y, z ],
    rot: [ x, y, z, w ],
    scl: [ x, y, z ] },

    { time: 620,
    rot: [ x, y, z, w ] },

    { time: 1201,
     pos: [ x, y, z ],
     rot: [ x, y, z, w ],
     scl: [ x, y, z ] } ] },

    { parent: 0,
     keys: [ ...
     ] }
```

However with all the structure set, the object does not get animated.

Here are the main part of the code :

```
            //setting up geometry with geometry.bones, geometry.skinWeights, geometry.skinIndices
            //setting up animation following the format described above
            skinMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({skinning: true});
            skinMesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, skinMaterial);
            skinAnimation = new THREE.Animation(skinMesh, animation);
            skinAnimation.play();
```

Is there something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe helps: https://devmatrix.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/creating-skeletal-animation-in-blender-and-exporting-it-to-three-js/

Comment: have you added `THREE.AnimationHandler.update(/*deltaTime*/)` in your render callback ?